# Mootools class - Object.keys() on object property

Tags: mootools

Consider this simple Mootools class :

```
var Garden  = new Class({
    fruits : {
        banana : 'yellow',
        kiwi : 'brown',
        strawberry : 'red'
    },
    initialize : function() {
        console.log(this.fruits);
        console.log(this.fruits.banana);
        console.log(Object.keys(this.fruits));
    }
});
var g = new Garden;
```

Output (in Chrome console) :

```
reset.F
yellow
[]
```

The third line should be : ['banana', 'kiwi', 'strawberry']
The problem is situated in the Mootools reset method that creates a new object with the original fruits object as its prototype. Since Object.keys iterates checking for hasOwnProperty, it returns an empty array.

Any idea on how to get the expected output ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will get you the expected output:

```
var Garden  = new Class({
    fruits : {
        banana : 'yellow',
        kiwi : 'brown',
        strawberry : 'red'
    },
    initialize : function() {
        console.log(this.fruits);
        console.log(this.fruits.banana);
        var foo = Object.clone(this.fruits);
        console.log(Object.keys(foo));
    }
});
var g = new Garden();
```

however - as to why it's happening - because fruits has inherited properties only, when you clone it, it clones the inherited properties to the new object as to dereference them

Comment: you can also wrap the object in an array eg. fruit: [{whatever}] and it'll work. This seems like an error in mootools to me. I'm using Mootools 1.4.5

Comment: how is it an error in mootools? this is simple object inheritance up the prototype chain. `optionsObj = { foo: "bar"}`, `constructorObj: { options: optionsObj }` - passed by dereference to the prototype. but from prototype to instance is by reference as the instance inherits the options object. `instance.options == constructor.prototype.options` so: `constructor.prototype.options.foo = "foo";` -> `instance.options.foo === "foo";` as it's up the prototype chain. see http://jsfiddle.net/d4VLw/

Comment: to illustrate it further - see when setOptions is being used that merges an option object: http://jsfiddle.net/d4VLw/1/ and before that, object keys come back empty: http://jsfiddle.net/d4VLw/2/

Comment: Yeah, I see it now. I just ran into this myself for the first time today after using mootools for years now. I guess I and just thought mootools was setting default values on the object not the prototype. Looking at the Class code though, it makes sense.